# Split string with specific requirements

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, split

Let's say I have the string

```
string Song = "The-Sun - Is Red";
```

I need to split it from the '-' char, but only if the char before and after is a space.

I don't want it to split at "The-Sun"'s dash, but rather at "Sun - Is"'s dash.

The code I was using to split was

```
string[] SongTokens = Song.Split('-');
```

But that obviously splits at the first I believe. I only need to split if it has a space before and after the '-'

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to split it from the '-' char, but only if the char before and after is a space.

You can use a non-regex solution like this:

```
string[] SongTokens = Song.Split(new[] {" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Result:

[image]

See more details about [`String.Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) at MSDN. The first argument is *separator* that represent a *string array that delimits the substrings in this string, an empty array that contains no delimiters, or `null`*.

The `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` removes all empty elements from the resulting array. You may use `StringSplitOptions.None` to keep the empty elements.

Yet there can be a problem if you have a hard space or a regular space on both ends. Then, you'd rather choose a regex solution like this:

```
string[] SongTokens = Regex.Split(Song, @"\p{Zs}+-\p{Zs}+")
            .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
            .ToArray();
```

The `\p{Zs}+` pattern matches any Unicode "horizontal" whitespace, 1 or more occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] SongTokens = Song.Split(new string[] {" - "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd put you as the answer but the user above you went into detail, but your code also works perfectly!